# JComboBox using swing invalid,layout when printed and NullPointerException on Apple but not Windows

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am using Swing to build a simple GUI with a JCombobox for Java.
The GUI loads on my PC, but causes a NullPointerException on my partners Apple computer.

I tried to print out the JComboBox and I get the following "invalid" message. Does anyone know what might cause the "...invalid, layout..." and why the JComboBox causes a NullPointerException on an apple but not Windows laptop?

Message when I print out the JComboBox:

> Jcombobox javax.swing.JComboBox[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxUI$MetalComboBoxLayoutManager,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=328,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isEditable=false,lightWeightPopupEnabled=true,maximumRowCount=8,selectedItemReminder=Search your own pasted text]

I actually found the same "invalid" when I tried printing out the JComboBox from Oracle's tutorial site: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ComboBoxDemoProject/src/components/ComboBoxDemo.java
[NOTE: by printing out JCombox petlist]:

```
  public ComboBoxDemo() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        String[] petStrings = { "Bird", "Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Pig" };

        //Create the combo box, select the item at index 4.
        //Indices start at 0, so 4 specifies the pig.
        JComboBox petList = new JComboBox(petStrings);
        petList.setSelectedIndex(4);
        petList.addActionListener(this);
        System.out.println(petList);
```

Below also, is our code for the project we are making [just the JComboBox section:

```
public String comboBox() {
        String str = "Search Lyric Database";
        String[] options = new String[] { "Search Lyric Database", "Search Books Database", "Search your own file", "Search website",
                "Search your own pasted text" };

        JComboBox<String> bookList = new JComboBox<>(options);
        bookList.setSelectedIndex(3);
        System.out.println("JCOMBOBOX" + bookList );

        pane.add(bookList, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

And note the "invalid" in the output [when printed] from a windows computer.

> ...javax.swing.JComboBox[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.......

Does anyone know what the "invalid" means?
Does anyone have any insight into why when the JCombobox is clicked from an Apple computer it causes a nullPointerException [but not on a Windows] and how we can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the entire error message and stack trace you are getting when you run your code on your partner's _Apple_ computer.

Comment: *Does anyone have any insight into why when the JCombobox is clicked from an Apple computer it causes a nullPointerException [but not on a Windows] and how we can fix this?* - post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. Make sure you create all the components on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) as is demonstrated in the code from the Swing tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "invalid" basically means that `Component.isValid()` returns false (https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/awt/Component.java#L8134).

According to the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isValid()) the `isValid()` method

> Determines whether this component is valid. A component is valid when it is correctly sized and positioned within its parent container and all its children are also valid. In order to account for peers' size requirements, components are invalidated before they are first shown on the screen. By the time the parent container is fully realized, all its components will be valid.

So this probably just means that you never added this JComboBox to a container and/or that this container was never displayed (yet).

So this surely is not the cause for your `NullPointerException`